# last reboot -F shows overlapping timespans

Tags: linux, boot, monitoring, last

I just found some odd behaviour on one of our servers that I can't explain myself.
It is about both middle lines. I would assume that the timespans for the boot user must not overlap, however, they do:

```
$ last reboot -F
reboot   system boot  4.4.44-39.55.amz Wed Feb 15 09:16:30 2017 - Wed Feb 15 09:36:53 2017  (00:20)    
reboot   system boot  4.4.41-36.55.amz Fri Feb 10 20:16:26 2017 - Wed Feb 15 09:16:00 2017 (4+12:59)   
reboot   system boot  4.4.41-36.55.amz Fri Feb 10 14:33:56 2017 - Wed Feb 15 09:16:00 2017 (4+18:42)   
reboot   system boot  4.4.35-33.55.amz Fri Jan 20 17:06:05 2017 - Wed Feb 15 09:16:00 2017 (25+16:09)
```

Does this mean the machine was not properly shutdown before rebooted, so there is no logout entry of the boot user in `wtmp`?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are not entries of a `boot` user logging in or out, it's the system writing an entry upon reboot.

The entries are written when a reboot occurs, however, if the system was brought down in some other way (by unplugging the power or whatever), an entry would not have been written. I presume that the next orderly shutdown would therefore produce the effect that you are seeing.

Rebooting with `reboot -d` will also not update the `wtmp` database.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. I assumed that on boot the system would check if there is a shutdown entry and otherwise add one to keep the time spans intact. So it's not strict state-machine behaviour. Nice to know!

Comment: @ThomasFankhauser No, AFAIK, the `wtmp` database is only updated when someone logs out or when the system shuts down.

Comment: So  duplicates dates are crash rather than clean shutdown?

Comment: @MUYBelgium That's a likely explanation, yes.