# Why reboot time is incorrect in last -x

Tags: time, reboot

My server suddenly crashed and rebooted today and I want to find the reason.

```
me@raspberrypi$ last -x
me       pts/0        xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  Mon Feb 27 13:43   still logged in
me       tty1                          Mon Feb 27 12:17   still logged in
runlevel (to lvl 3)   4.4.46-v7+       Mon Feb 27 12:17 - 14:01  (01:43)
reboot   system boot  4.4.46-v7+       Thu Jan  1 08:00 - 14:01 (17224+06:01
me       tty1                          Mon Feb 27 10:17 - crash (-17224+-2:-
runlevel (to lvl 3)   4.4.46-v7+       Mon Feb 27 10:17 - 12:17  (02:00)
reboot   system boot  4.4.46-v7+       Thu Jan  1 08:00 - 14:01 (17224+06:01
me       pts/0        xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  Sun Feb 26 13:36 - 18:39  (05:03)
```

and all my boot info's timestamp is 0:

```
reboot   system boot  4.4.46-v7+       Thu Jan  1 08:00:19 1970 - Mon Feb 27 16:20:42 2017 (17224+08:20
reboot   system boot  4.4.46-v7+       Thu Jan  1 08:00:13 1970 - Mon Feb 27 16:20:42 2017 (17224+08:20
reboot   system boot  4.4.46-v7+       Thu Jan  1 08:00:01 1970 - Mon Feb 27 16:20:42 2017 (17224+08:20
reboot   system boot  4.4.46-v7+       Thu Jan  1 08:00:13 1970 - Sun Feb 19 03:15:42 2017 (17215+19:15
reboot   system boot  4.4.46-v7+       Thu Jan  1 08:00:01 1970 - Sun Feb 19 03:15:42 2017 (17215+19:15
reboot   system boot  4.4.46-v7+       Thu Jan  1 08:00:01 1970 - Fri Feb 17 12:44:37 2017 (17214+04:44
reboot   system boot  4.4.38-v7+       Thu Jan  1 08:00:24 1970 - Sun Feb  5 21:07:30 2017 (17202+13:07
reboot   system boot  4.4.38-v7+       Thu Jan  1 08:00:16 1970 - Sun Feb  5 21:07:30 2017 (17202+13:07
```

Why the reboot time is always `Thu Jan  1 08:00`?
Also, how to point why it rebooted, overheated or power outage?

Comment: How do you shut down your system?

Comment: @Kusalananda, this is what I want to figure out. I just know the system have rebooted. But don't know what happened to it.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345162/last-reboot-f-shows-overlapping-timespans

Comment: When you call `last -F`it will give you full date and time; you will see that boot always happens on Jan 1st, 1970. Raspberry Pi by default has no realtime clock, so when booting time is always reset to 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. When booting, it gets the actual time and date via NTP, and from that on it will be correct. If you want correct boot time, you need to add an RTC module. And you may look for messages before reboot in /var/log/syslog to find the reason.