# Ubuntu last reboot - repeating end time

Tags: ubuntu, reboot, last, wtmp

I'm seeing the following events and I'm not sure why and how.

```
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec 31 13:31:03 2019   still running
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec 30 14:15:35 2019 - Tue Dec 31 13:30:46 2019  (23:15)
reboot   system boot  Sun Dec 29 14:17:08 2019 - Tue Dec 31 13:30:46 2019 (1+23:13)
reboot   system boot  Sun Dec 29 12:30:47 2019 - Tue Dec 31 13:30:46 2019 (2+00:59)
reboot   system boot  Sat Dec 28 12:53:02 2019 - Tue Dec 31 13:30:46 2019 (3+00:37)
reboot   system boot  Tue Jul  3 20:00:46 2018 - Tue Dec 31 13:30:46 2019 (545+18:30)
reboot   system boot  Tue Jul  3 20:00:49 2018 - Tue Dec 31 13:30:46 2019 (545+18:29)
reboot   system boot  Fri Dec 27 23:47:17 2019 - Tue Dec 31 13:30:46 2019 (3+13:43)
reboot   system boot  Fri Dec 27 23:46:20 2019 - Tue Dec 31 13:30:46 2019 (3+13:44)
reboot   system boot  Fri Dec 27 01:00:09 2019 - Tue Dec 31 13:30:46 2019 (4+12:30)
reboot   system boot  Fri Dec 27 00:30:44 2019 - Tue Dec 31 13:30:46 2019 (4+13:00)
```

1. Why does the same end date (Dec 31 13:30:46 2019) appear so many times? Shouldn't the end date be close to the next reboot date?
2. What could have caused the the Jul 3 date to pop in there?

Edit:

```
last --version 
last from util-linux 2.27.1
```

Comment: This is the output of `last reboot`?  The format I get differs from what you show above.  Can you update your question with the output of `last --version`?

Comment: @AndyDalton Looks more like `last -RF reboot`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [last reboot -F shows overlapping timespans](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345162/last-reboot-f-shows-overlapping-timespans)